# JRockit Mission Control: Analyze Hot methods from JFR

Tags: java, jrockit

We are trying to analyze `JFR` using `JRockit Mission Control`. On the `JFR`, we have the 'Code' tab which has '`Hot Packages`' and '`Hot Methods`' sub tabs. The `Hot Methods` is very helpful but generally the `Hot methods` are some Java API methods like `java.util.HashMap.get(Object)` or `JVM` specific methods like `jrockit.vm.ArrayCopy.copy(Object, int, Object, int, int)`.

But to find out which application code triggered these methods, we need to drill down the tree(s) of the predecessors. In other words, there is no search on the stack traces of the predecessors. Is there anyway that I can enable search on the predecessors' stack traces so that I can track down which application code is actually triggering the hot methods..?

Thanks,
Siva Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

You can't search for stack traces in JMC